# Spaces on Dynamic PIVOT column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, whitespace

I have the next portion of code in SQL Server:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME([c].[Name])
                    FROM #features c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT [Id], 
                     [Url], 
                     [Title], 
                     [Address], 
                     [Domain], 
                     [Price], 
                     [Code],
                     [Image]
                     ' + @cols + '
               FROM (SELECT [Id], 
                            [Url], 
                            [Title], 
                            [Address], 
                            [Domain], 
                            [Price], 
                            [Code],
                            [Image], 
                            [Value] AS [value], 
                            [Name] AS [name] 
                     FROM #temptable) x 
                     PIVOT(max(value) for name in (' + @cols + ')) p';
```

Which returns me the rows in `Name` as columns with `Values` as the corresponding values. No problem with that. But I'm using Dapper to make execute the queries in .NET and, after notice that those dynamic columns was not being mapped to my class, I started to research and found the following was being retrieved:

[image: SQL Server response]

So, those properties with `\r\n` are giving me problems with the mapping thing. I was trying to remove those spaces in columns without success. Any idea of how to solve that?

**UPDATE:**

The definition of `#features` and `#temptable` is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #features
(
    [Id] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(80)
)

CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [Id] INT,
    [Url] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Title] NVARCHAR(300),
    [Address] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Domain] Tinyint,
    [Price] Real,
    [Code] NVARCHAR(10),
    [Image] NVARCHAR(150), 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(80),
    [Value] NVARCHAR(150)
)
```

With the original section of

```
SET @cols = STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME([c].[Name])
                    FROM #features c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

I obtain the following:

[image: Correct values]

BUT, If I replace that segment with

```
SET @cols = REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME([c].[Name])
                    FROM #features c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

I obtain null in those dynamic columns

[image: Null values after remove \r\n]

**UPDATE 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE #features
(
    [Id] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(80)
)

INSERT INTO #features
    SELECT [Id], [Name] 
    FROM Feature

SELECT DISTINCT
    ', [' + [f].[Name] + ']'
FROM #features f
```

Gives the following

[image: Results of brackets added]

But the `Name` field has no spaces in the value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute the following code, I do get a suitable output:

```
SET @cols = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                    ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE([c].[Name], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))
              FROM #features c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''));

SET @query = 'SELECT [Id], 
                     [Url], 
                     [Title], 
                     [Address], 
                     [Domain], 
                     [Price], 
                     [Code],
                     [Image]
                     ' + @cols + '
               FROM (SELECT [Id], 
                            [Url], 
                            [Title], 
                            [Address], 
                            [Domain], 
                            [Price], 
                            [Code],
                            [Image], 
                            [Value] AS [value], 
                            [Name] AS [name] 
                     FROM #temptable) x 
                     PIVOT(max(value) for name in (' + @cols + ')) p';
EXEC (@query);
```

I think you'll need to give us some sample data for both tables to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I was able to remove the \r\n substring, but now I receive null in those columns. I will update the question with images of the results before and after, as well as the definition of the #temptable and #features

Comment: Great. That'd help a lot. - Sample code and expected output

Comment: Hi, you'll really need some sample data, and the overall query that you're trying to execute. I'll try to execute it but I suspect that a SET statement for the @cols won't be enough.

Comment: If I add the following:
```
INSERT #features (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Antiquity'), (2, 'Bathrooms'), (3, 'Bedrooms'), (4, 'HalfBaths'), (5, 'Parking Lot'), (6, 'Roofed Surface'), (7, 'TotalArea');
```
then the list of columns looks ok:
[Antiquity],[Bathrooms],[Bedrooms],[HalfBaths],[Parking Lot],[Roofed Surface],[TotalArea]
we'll need sample data and query to do more

Comment: I think the problem is on QUOTENAME, cause `Select QUOTENAME([Name]) from feature` gives me the blank spaces back, but without QUOTENAME, I don't see them. Weird...

Comment: I now realise you're trying to dynamically build an IN list. Try the modified code.

Comment: It's still detecting the break line, but the NAME field has no space in the value itself. Also, I updated the question one more time

Comment: Try the amended one again

Comment: It's detecting an error next to the first column 
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near 'Antiquity'.`

Comment: What would be good is if you could supply the query that you're trying to build, as a static query, then we can try to make it dynamic for you.

Comment: Is it possible that the type has anything to do with this? I mean, I'm using a `NVARCHAR(80)` for that field `Name`, and if I do a simple select to retrieve only that column for that table, I can see those blank spaces also. But, as said, no one of the records has blank spaces if I try to modify them directly

Comment: You can have more context on this link, because it was a question related for the same query, but the full version. It was optimized now, but the results and the intention is the same: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266647/optimization-of-a-query-to-retrieve-records-randomly-with-multiple-joins-and-fil

Comment: I've added another and it's closer back to what you started with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213528/discussion-between-adolfo-f-ibarra-landeo-and-greg-low).